# Highest 16-bit of EAX

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, pci

I want to form a PCI address. How can I write 16-bit to the EAX (not to AX) in assembly language??
Example: write 0b1000000000000001

```
EAX before
|_____16-bit_____||_______AX_______|
EAX after:
|1000000000000001||_______AX_______|
```

Thanks!

Comment: EAX can only be accessed as the full 32 bits, so you'll have to left shift your value.

Comment: How about `OR`ing it with a masked value (something like `10000000000000010000000000000000`)?

Comment: The `OR`ing is one of decision, but what is about use stack?

Comment: `MOV EAX, 0b1000000000000001 << 16` if using NASM. Else use SHL.

Comment: One possibility is to use 'bswap eax'; mov ax,imm16_byte_reversed; 'bswap eax'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to access the higher 16 bits, but you can use a little trick:

```
push    ax
mov     ax, 1000000000000001b
shl     eax, 16
pop     ax
```

This sets the higher 16 bits to any value you want without destroying the lower 16 bits.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do it, here are some.

Using the stack, doesn't modify any flags:

```
push eax
mov  [esp+2],word 0b1000000000000001 ; some assemblers want word ptr
pop  eax
```

Rotating to left or right, doesn't need stack, but modifies flags:

```
rol  eax,16                ; rol / ror
mov  ax,0b1000000000000001
rol  eax,16                ; rol / ror
```

For hardcoded values (as in the question), you can also use `and` with `or`/`xor`/`add`. For non-hardcoded values you would need to shift the value in some other register or in memory to use this method:

```
and  eax,0x0000ffff
or   eax,0x80010000       ; or / xor / add
```

Comment: Thanks, and which variant is better (faster)?

Comment: @Vanzef For hardcoded values, I assume the last one. Other have 3 instructions and all instructions are dependent on results of previous instructions, so they can't be executed simultaneously. The last `and`, `or` solution has only 2 instructions, so I believe it's generally the fastest of these.